# Receiving error in Datasource when attempting insert command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datasource

I am getting the following error message when attempting the InsertCommand of the datasource:

***Procedure or function 'student_insert' expects parameter '@password', which was not supplied.***

I have most of the parameters set up in the ASCX page, except for 'password', since I need to do some manipulation to it before saving it in the DB:

```
<InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="university" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="program" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="student_number" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="graduation_date" Type="DateTime" ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$txtGradDate" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="student_card_image_name" Type="String" ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$FUStudent" PropertyName="FileName" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="id_card_image_name" Type="String" ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$FUID" PropertyName="FileName" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void datasource_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            ControlParameter cp = new ControlParameter("@password", DbType.Binary, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$txtPassword", "Text");
            FormView frmStudents = (FormView)FindControl("frmStudents");
            TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)(frmStudents.FindControl("txtPassword"));

            datasource.InsertParameters.Add("password", DbType.Binary, encoding.GetBytes(Cryptogrpahy.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text, basepage.crypt_password)).ToString());
        }
```

When I go through the method with the debugger, I see my entire InsertParameters, with values...

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Also, on a side note, not sure this will execute successfully due to the DB Type, as I usually use VarBinary in regular SQLParamater.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation on it, but I suspect what is happening is that the SqlCommand object that gets created during the Insert event is getting its parameters from the state of the SqlDataSource.InsertParameters object BEFORE your event handler code executes.  You're adding the parameter to the SqlDataSource, but since the SqlCommand was created and received its parameters from the SqlDataSource instance before you added the parameter to the SqlDataSource instance the SqlCommand never gets the password parameter.

To get around this try adding the password parameter to `e.Command.Parameters` in your event handler instead of to `datasource`.

```
protected void datasource_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            ControlParameter cp = new ControlParameter("@password", DbType.Binary, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl01$frmStudents$txtPassword", "Text");
            FormView frmStudents = (FormView)FindControl("frmStudents");
            TextBox txtPassword = (TextBox)(frmStudents.FindControl("txtPassword"));

            e.Command.Parameters.Add("password", DbType.Binary, encoding.GetBytes(Cryptogrpahy.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text, basepage.crypt_password)).ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working. e.Command.Parameters.Add only accepts one parameter and I tried passing the value with no luck.